# How to add bullets to description lists?

Tags: lists, description

I would like to add a bullet in front of every `\item[]`, i.e.

```
Hello,
\begin{description}
 \item[bla] blubb
\end{description}
```

becomes

> Hello,
>     **bla** blubb

I quickly found how to remove them from itemize statements, but not the inverse.
So, I would like to know how to prepend every description's item label with something.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It would probably be better if you create your own list type using enumitem's `\newlist` feature.

If you don't want to do so, here's a hack, but it is somehow maintainable: Use the `enumitem` package and do the following:

```
\begin{description}[font=$\bullet$\scshape\bfseries]
```

That is, you encode the special stuff in the thing that should be your font, but it works fine, as long as the `$\bullet` (or equivalent) is in front of the actual description label.

---

[image: markiDescriptionBullet]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\blindtext Coco likes fruit. Her favorites are:
\begin{description}[font=$\bullet$~\normalfont\scshape\color{red!50!black}]
\item [Bananas] yellow and banana shaped
\item [Apples] red and round
\item [Oranges] orange and round
\item [Lemons] yellow, kinda round
\end{description}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: The following works really nice when put in the preamble: `\usepackage{enumitem}\setlist[description]{font=\textendash\enskip\scshape\bfseries}`

Comment: Works like a charm, but if the item text goes beyond one line, the wrapped text is not aligned properly.

Comment: Still works perfectly. Tested under Texworks and Miktex 21 under Windows 10.

Comment: I had to do two things to get suggestions here to work.
1. color didn't work until I added `\usepackage{xcolor}` to the preamble.
2. scshape didn't work until I added `\normalfont` right before it to clear previous font settings.

Answer (score 57):

One quick way is to do it manually for each bullet:

```
\begin{description}
  \item[$\cdot$ bla1] item 1
  \item[$\bullet$ bla2] item 2
  \item[$\ast$ bla3] item 3
\end{description}
```

This produces:

[image]

Comment: Obviously, that is not what I planned to do :-)

Comment: @Marki - there may be a way to do it for each item as a `renewcommand`, but the quick and dirty way works.  Even with a lot of `item`s, you could do a search/replace and put in the `$\cdot$` command for each item.  But, maybe someone will come along and present a different way to do it.

Comment: Though this was not the OP asked, I thank you @chris Gregg, as it was useful to me ;)

Comment: Hi, could you build subitem under your prescription? I used "\subitem[$\cdot$ bla1] item 1", it gives me "[. bla1] item1". I do not want the "[]".

Comment: I don't get it what is wrong with `itemize`? e.g. `\begin{itemize}

\item one.

\item two. 

\item three.

\end{itemize}` 

https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Lists

Answer (score 27):

You can use the itemization function (https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Lists)

```
\begin{itemize}

\item one.

\item two. 

\item three.

\end{itemize}
```

And the output:

[image]

Comment: The question asks for `description` lists. Not itemize.

Comment: Thanks for adding this answer nevertheless. Helped me with my issue.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can globally redefine the `\descriptionlabel[1]` to whatever you want.

In the case of this question, something like :

```
\renewcommand\descriptionlabel[1]{$\bullet$ \textbf{#1}}
```

### The output

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\renewcommand\descriptionlabel[1]{$\bullet$ \textbf{#1}}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{description}
  \item [myDescriptionLabel] myItem
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't get it what is wrong with `itemize`? e.g. `\begin{itemize}

\item one.

\item two. 

\item three.

\end{itemize}` 

https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Lists